# Using Timer loop in Javascript Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

The following does not loop:

```
function sequencer(){
    //empty for proof of concept
}
sequencer.prototype.start = function(){
    console.log("not looping");
    tid = setTimeout(this.start, 2000);
}

one = new sequencer();
one.start();
```

The following does loop:

```
function start() {
    console.log("looping");
    tid = setTimeout(start, 2000); 
}

start();
```

Why does the function declared as a method of a class behave differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This because when a function in `setTimeout` is called, its context is set to `window`.  It's like it's being called as:

```
this.start.call(window)
```

So, when `start()` is called again, `this` is `window` and since `window.start` doesn't exist, it doesn't run again.

You can try it like this:

```
setTimeout(this.start.bind(this), 2000);
```

Comment: @KevinBowersox: Though I think "strict mode" might change that.

Answer (score 1):

When called the second time `this` is not the the sequencer instance it is the window object.  Create a simple closure to capture `this`.

```
function sequencer(){
    //empty for proof of concept
}
sequencer.prototype.start = function(){
    var that = this;
    console.log("not looping");
    setTimeout(function(){that.start()}, 2000);
}

var one = new sequencer();
one.start();
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/F4HgD/

Comment: `this is not the object`. it's better to say it's not a sequencer instance. because `window` is object too.

Comment: @dfsq: `this` is not the object you expected :-)